# embed code in AJAX error

Tags: javascript, ajax, embed

I'm trying to make the embed by using AJAX to call the embed code because I have many channels and I don't want to use PHP echo

I use this code

```
embedios="<video x-webkit-airplay=\"allow\"> ";
embedios=embedios+"<source src=\""+stream+"\" type=\"video/mp4\"> ";
embedios=embedios+"<!-- other sources and fallbacks go here --></video> ";
embed=embedios;
```

and the problem is that the output come out like this

```
<video x-webkit-airplay="allow" tabindex="0">
<source type="video/mp4" src="http://yoursn0w.com/ch3.m3u8 "></source>
<!-- other sources and fallbacks go here -->
</video>
```

but instead I want it to come out like this

```
<video x-webkit-airplay="allow"> 
  <source src="http://yoursn0w.com/ch3.m3u8" type="video/mp4"> 
  <!-- other sources and fallbacks go here --> 
</video>
```

I dont know what I did wrong in this code

Comment: Can you please more detailed with your question what are you doing? what's stream so on.

Comment: sorry I have edit my code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't terminating your strings:

```
embedios="<video x-webkit-airplay=\"allow\">"
embedios=embedios+"<source src=\""+stream+"\" type=\"video/mp4\">"
embedios=embedios+"<!-- other sources and fallbacks go here --></video>"
embed=embedios;
```

Comment: You should be able to in the video tag, but drop the `px`. So width=\"635\" height=\"448\"

Comment: sorry I just figure that the video tag should be on the airplay line not the soruce line ^^" so now all worked fine :D

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes are not matching properly.

```
var embedios='<video x-webkit-airplay=\"allow\">'
embedios=embedios+'<source src=\""+stream+"\" type=\"video/mp4\">'
embedios=embedios+'<!-- other sources and fallbacks go here --></video>'
embed=embedios;
```

Comment: I tried yours and your output come like this

    enter code here<video x-webkit-airplay="allow" tabindex="0">
<source type="video/mp4" +stream+""="" src=""></source>
<!-- other sources and fallbacks go here -->
</video>